# How is sentence stress in German different than in English?

Tags: phonetics

Content words (i.e. verbs, nouns, adjectives, adverbs) are stressed in both German and English as opposed to function words (prepositions, pronouns, articles..). However, in English (at least in American accent) in neutral speech, content words aren't equally stressed, but some words are more pronounced than the others.

Examples (words in **bold** are more pronouncedly stressed):

> A nice **car**- ein schönes Auto
>
> A **really** nice **car**- ein wirklich schönes Auto
>
> Bob **Smith**- Bob Smith
>
> Bob's **brother**- Bobs Bruder
>
> Zinc **oxide**- Zinkoxid
>
> New **York**- New York
>
> History of **Africa**- Geschichte von Afrika
>
> The white **house** (its color is white)- Das weiße Haus
>
> The **White** house (of the American president)- Das Weiße Haus

Does German have a tendency to stress some content words more than the others? Does it follow the English pattern? Is it in German more of equally stressed content words?

**Note:** I fully understand that we can stress ANY word in a sentence contrastively to emphasize it. I also understand that German tends to stress more the last lexical word in a phrase. However, my question is not about these situations, it's not about stressing content words contrastively or when they occur as the last lexical word.

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with most items in Jankas list. You don't stress words, you stress syllables. I think more correct are:

> - ein **schön**es **Au**to
> - ein **schön**es **rot**es **Au**to
> - ein **wirk**lich **schön**es **rot**es **Au**to
> - **Bob Smith**
> - **Bobs Bru**der
> - **Bob** und **Cy**ril **Smith**
> - **Zink**oxid
> - **Ab**deck- und **Zink**oxid**sal**be
> - **New York**
> - San Fran**cis**co
> - Bad **Harz**burg
> - Ge**schich**te **A**frikas
> - Das **wei**ße **Haus**
> - Das **Wei**ße **Haus**

If you have more than one stressed syllable in one sentence of phrase, it strongly depends on the context, which of those syllables gets the most stress.

In the 3rd example *(ein wirklich schönes rotes Auto)* in most situations you would give the biggest stress to *wirk* in *wirklich*, but there might be situations where you want to stress another word.

I never heard any difference between any house with a white facade and the US-presidents home. Because its part of a proper name, you just capitalize »Weiße« in case of the presidents home, while you leave it lower case if it is just any house, but you do not pronounce or stress it differently.

---

### Addendum

Abdullah asked in [his comment](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/47159/how-is-sentence-stress-in-german-different-than-in-english/47170?noredirect=1#comment114270_47170):

> ... My question if I may put it in another words, for example in *ein schönes Auto,* which syllable do you think is more pronounced *schö* or *Au*? Or they are equally stressed and take the same duration of time and voice power? This applies for the rest of my examples.

As I already tried to explain: This strongly depends on the context. I give you two examples:

1. > A: Warum musst du deine alte Rostlaube direkt vor meinem Hauseingang abstellen? Wie sieht das denn aus? Kannst du deine schäbige Karre nicht schräg gegenüber, vor dieser baufälligen Hütte abstellen? Dort würde sie besser hinpassen als vor meine Villa.
   >   B: Jetzt pass einmal auf, mein Freund. Mein Auto ist weder eine alte Rostlaube noch eine schäbige Karre. Ich gebe zu, es ist nicht mehr ganz neu, aber ich finde, es ist *ein **schönes** Auto.* Es hat eben Charakter, ganz im Gegensatz zu dir.

   Here A says to B that B's car is rusty, old and shabby, but B is defending this car. B wants to highlight, that the car is beautiful, and therefore the word *»schönes«* is much more stressed than every other word in B's speech.
2. > C: Na, Fräulein Tochter, du wirst ja bald 18. Was wünscht du dir denn zum Geburtstag? Möchtest du eine schöne Handtasche, oder vielleicht ein schönes Kleid?
   >   D: Ganz ehrlich? Ich will lieber *ein schönes **Auto.*** Es muss auch gar nicht teuer sein.

   Here one of the parents asks a young lady what she wants for her 18<sup>th</sup> birthday. A beautiful handbag? Or a beautiful dress? In her answer the daughter wants to put the focus on the fact, that it better should be a car, and so here the word *Auto* is stressed more than anything else in the whole speech.

This applies for the rest of all examples.

Comment: I think we are talking about two different things here. The question was about the English habit of "naturally" emphasizing certain words in a sentence, not about how to choose the stressed syllable in a word.

Comment: Thank you very much. I do agree that we don't stress words, but we stress *the stressed syllable* in that word. That is definitely the case in English. My question if I may put it in another words, for example in *ein schönes Auto*, which syllable do you think is more pronounced *schö* or *Au*? Or they are equally stressed and take the same duration of time and voice power? This applies for the rest of my examples.

Comment: @Abdullah: See the addendum in my answer.

Comment: An ordinary simple man who doesn't know what AIDS stands for, opens his dictionary and starts reading: "Aids bezeichnet eine **spezifische Kombination** von Symptomen, die beim Menschen infolge der durch **Infektion** mit dem **Humanen Immun**defizienz-Virus (HI-Virus, HIV) **induzierten Zerstörung** des Immunsystems auftreten." This man doesn’t want to stress any word contrastively to make a special point or to draw attention or emphasis to it. He doesn't want to know or  even care about specific details. I deduce from your answer, such content words **in bold** receive the same stress power?

Comment: @Abdullah: Another simple man might read the same sentence with other stress-points: »**Aids** bezeichnet eine **spezifische Kombination** von **Symptomen**, die beim **Menschen** infolge der durch Infektion mit dem **Humanen Immun**defizienz-Virus (**HI-Virus, HIV**) induzierten Zerstörung des **Immunsystems** auftreten.« And a thrid person might set his/her focuses even to other words. It really depends very strong on the context. The stress power is not equal. It varies in a wide range, depending on the speakers mood and intention.

Comment: What is always the same, is the syllable within a word that will be stressed. It does not matter, if *»Infektion«* gets a strong stress within the sentence, but within this word always *tion* will be stressed more than *Infek*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Some say there can be nothing out of context like you suggest. Maybe this issue is less obvious in German than in English (like it is in reducing non-stressed vowels to schwas). In books like *American Accent Training* by Ann Cook or *Improve your American English Accent* by Charlsie Childs, the authors suggest it’s an important aspect of American English. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

The natural stress is on the most "topical" part of an item. English is similar but there is sometimes a dispute which part of an item is the topic:

> ein **schönes** Auto
>
> ein **schönes rotes** Auto
>
> ein **wirklich** schönes rotes Auto
>
> Bob **Smith**
>
> Bobs **Bruder**
>
> **Bob** und **Cyril** Smith
>
> **Zink**oxid
>
> **Abdeck-** und **Zink**oxidsalbe
>
> New **York**
>
> **San** Francisco
>
> **Bad** Harzburg
>
> **Geschichte** Afrikas
>
> Das **weiße** Haus
>
> Das **Weiße Haus**

Comment: Thank you a lot. Could you please elaborate more about what you mean by *topical part*? Is it the determiner that conveys the new information? I know *Geschichte von Afrika* is stilted but I used it on purpose to see where the stress would fall in relation to *von*, will it also be on *Geschichte*?

Comment: Yes, the determiner that conveys new or most specific information. For either *Geschichte Afrikas* and *Geschichte von Afrika*, the "natural" stress would be on *Geschichte*, because that's the natural topic. It's about history, not about anything else someone could tell about Africa.

Comment: Hmmm... I would stress as *San **Francisco*** and *Bad **Harzburg***, but also *die Geschichte **Afrikas***.

Comment: I may be a matter of personal preference then.